# Authentication with Swift and PHP

Tags: php, swift, authentication

Let me preface this by saying that I’m fairly new to a lot of this. I am trying to securely implement authentication.

I have built a basic app using swift. It contains a login page that segues to a single view with a  webview. I need the user to login from the app itself rather than from a login screen within the webview. The reason for this is because I’d like to send location data from the device and send push notifications. So basically a successful login takes you to a big webview with all of the meat and potatoes of the app.

My problem is this. How do I create a secure environment in the webview after a user logs in on my app.

As of right now, the login data is sent via a post request to my PHP API. If successful, it generates a unique key and stores it in a MySQL database. It also returns this key to the swift app. The app then appends the key to all requests from the webview.

I’m looking for guidance in making this as secure as possible. I realize that that adding the webview probably adds a bit more vulnerability.

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately your question is too vague. "looking for guidance" is not a meaningful question, you need to be much more specific in what you ask about and this probably involves doing some more research first.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You'll need to be a lot more precise about the problem you want to ask about. What do you think the security issue is with your proposal, specifically?